# Menu using bootstrap Affix disappears on Safari iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have a menu that is fixed to the top of the page using bootstrap 'affix'. In a desktop browser, it, as expected stays fixed as the user scrolls up and down the page. However, in iOS, the menu dissapears off the page (see this short video demonstrating - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R4C0GYxarFA)

HTML

```
<nav data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="0" data-offset-bottom="0" id="navigation" class="btn-group navigation hidden" role="group" aria-label="Navigation">

    <div id="scroller">
     <a href="#page-top" aria-label="Home" role="button" class="btn btn-link page-scroll home-link mobile-reveal internal" title="Home"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span><span class="sr-only">Home</span></a>
      <a href="#about" role="button" class="btn btn-link page-scroll internal">About Us</a>
      <a href="#services-jumbo" role="button" class="btn btn-link page-scroll internal">Services</a>
       <a href="#page-top" aria-label="Home" role="button" class="btn btn-link page-scroll home-link mobile-hide internal" title="Home"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span><span class="sr-only">Home</span></a>
      <a href="#careers" role="button" class="btn btn-link page-scroll internal">Careers</a>
      <a href="#enquiries" role="button" class="btn btn-link page-scroll  internal">Enquiries</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

SCSS (i've taken out basic formatting):

```
#navigation {


  position: absolute;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  width:100%;
  min-height:35px;
    #scroller {
      position:absolute;
      left:0px;
      width:320px;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      overflow-x: scroll;
      overflow-scrolling:auto;
      -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

        .internal {
        display: inline;
       }
     }
   }
#navigation.affix {
  position:fixed;
}
```

Does anyone have an idea what is causing this behaviour, and how to fix it?

Many thanks